# How to start the Application in Symbian OS using J2ME?

Tags: java-me, symbian, nokia, s60-5th-edition

I'm new to mobile development. 
I want to know the developing sites for Symbian OS Nokia development?
I'm working in eclipse pulsar,In J2ME language. Then how to develop the Application 
on S605th edition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download [java wireless toolkit](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-137162.html) and [configure](http://www.javamidlet.com/2008/01/18/how-to-setup-eclipse-for-mobile-java-development.html) with Eclipse Pulsar. [Symbian 5th edition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S60_%28software_platform%29) mobiles mostly Touch enabled mobiles. Look at [Nokia Developer Documentation](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Develop/Java/Getting_started/) for your reference.

**FYI:** You can use [LWUIT framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6152237/what-is-lwuit-light-weight-user-interface-toolkit). LWUIT provides swing like features and touch enabled by default.